# How to solve System.DateTime does not contain a definition for TryParseExact" on Windows CE and C#

Tags: c#, datetime, windows-mobile, windows-ce, tryparse

I have a block of C# code here.. Basically, what it does is, user input a string in textbox1, on button click, C# will check what date format it is with my declared formats, then add 6 months on the date and output it in the textbox2 to string format yyyyMMdd. I am trying to run this on Windows CE..

And I am having an error of "System.DateTime does not contain a definition for TryParseExact".

```
            DateTime dateValue;
            string inputString = textBox1.Text;
            string[] formats = {"yyyyMMdd", "yyyy.MM.dd", "dd-MMM-yy", "yyyy/MM/dd", "yyyy-MM-dd", "yy/MM/dd"};

            try
            {
                if (DateTime.TryParseExact(inputString, formats,
                                           null,
                                           DateTimeStyles.None,
                                           out dateValue))
                {
                    dateValue = dateValue.AddMonths(6);
                    textBox2.Text = dateValue.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Date Format.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
```

THANKS EVERYONE!

Comment: What .net framework version are you using?

Comment: @loy .net compact framework I supose

Comment: hmm..do you know what version? @wudzik

Comment: @loy nope ;/ but I'm almost sure that none of .net compact has TryParse

Comment: Just write your own, catch the FormatException and return false.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this explanation, it shows how to make your own tryparse, because compact framework does not have it's own.

http://www.yortondotnet.com/2009/11/tryparse-for-compact-framework.html